# JavaMelody not showing graphs

Tags: awt, tomcat5.5, rhel5

I have four virtual servers that were all cloned from an original system.  I have installed javamelody on all four but on two of them, the graphs do not appear in the monitoring pages.  Other images show fine.  I get the following error on both servers that are not working correctly.

I have found the suggestions to add:  -Djava.awt.headless=true   but the two servers that are working correctly do not have this in place.   Any suggestions?

Here is the Stack Trace of the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
      at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:68)
      at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1135)
      at org.jrobin.graph.ImageWorker.resize(Unknown Source)
      at org.jrobin.graph.ImageWorker.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at org.jrobin.graph.RrdGraph.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at net.bull.javamelody.JRobin.graph(JRobin.java:217)
      at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringController.doGraph(MonitoringController.java:342)
      at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringController.doReport(MonitoringController.java:168)
      at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringController.doActionIfNeededAndReport(MonitoringController.java:141)
      at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doMonitoring(MonitoringFilter.java:340)
      at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:170)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)`
```

Comment: Check the DISPLAY environment setting on each server, are they identical?